# Transactional Email template size limit

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, html

I'm trying to create some newsletter emails using magentos transaction email system but I've run into situation where when I save the template it cuts off the email at a certain point. Because of the nature of coding everythin in tables and inline css the html is quite large and for one particular email it is 79,000 characters and its getting cut off at around 65,000. So my question is: Is there a limit to the size of email templates and if so can it be changed??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came along the same issue with aheadworks "follow up email" extension. In my case I was able to fix the problem by changing the field type from "text" to "longtext" (table "aw_followup_queue", field "content"). The equivalent for default Magento is the table "newsletter_queue", field "newsletter_text".

Another work around when using default Magento newsletter can be to split up the template in multiple static blocks and calling them one after the other since in the table "newsletter_queue", field "newsletter_text" static block references will be kept 'as is' (in third party extensions the static block references usually [as per what I have seen so far] get replaced with the blocks content).